# Oracle SQL with group by without count

Tags: sql, group-by

We have a table `partners` and I wanted a sql statement that would return row 5 and 6 based on example data below. The logic is every `partner2` will have one default `partner1` which is identified by the field `XDFREL` having a value of `X`.

In some cases `XDFREL` has more than 1 populated, like for `partner1 = 08021262` in row 5 and 6. I need all the records from this table (not count) where `XDFREL` is greater than 1 for every `partner2`. An example of the result is that it would return records from row 5 and 6... because `partner2 08021262` has two records in `partner1` field where `XDFREL` has `X` populated.

Thanks in advance

```
No| Partner1|   Partner2|   DateFrom|   DateTo    | XDFREL
01| 07380858|   08021262|   2/1/2018|   12/31/9999| 
02| 07342746|   08021262|   2/1/2017|   12/31/9999| 
03| 07342744|   08021262|   8/7/2017|   12/31/9999| 
04| 07340195|   08021262|   5/4/2017|   12/31/9999| 
05| 07100325|   08021262|   1/1/2001|   12/31/9999| X
06| 07073790|   08021262|   2/1/2017|   12/31/9999| X
07| 07517785|   08427151|   8/7/2017|   12/31/9999| X
08| 07517786|   08427152|   8/8/2017|   12/31/9999| X
09| 07517787|   08427152|   8/8/2017|   12/31/9999|
```

I can get the count but I need actual value of `partner1`

```
select count(B5.PARTNER1), B5.PARTNER2
from partners B5 
where B5.XDFREL = 'X' 
and TO_DATE(B5.DATE_TO , 'YYYYMMDD') > TRUNC(sysdate)
group by  B5.PARTNER2
having count(B5.PARTNER1) > 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider joining back the aggregate query to unit level:

```
with agg AS (
   select count(B5.PARTNER1), B5.PARTNER2
   from partners B5 
   where B5.XDFREL = 'X' 
     and TO_DATE(B5.DATE_TO, 'YYYYMMDD') > TRUNC(sysdate)
   group by B5.PARTNER2
   having count(B5.PARTNER1) > 1
)

select p.PARTNER1, p.PARTNER2, P.DATE_TO
from partners p
inner join agg
   on p.PARTNER2 = agg.PARTNER2
  and p.XDFREL = 'X' 
  and TO_DATE(p.DATE_TO, 'YYYYMMDD') > TRUNC(sysdate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with EXISTS:

```
with cte as (
  select *
  from partners 
  where XDFREL = 'X' and TO_DATE(DATE_TO , 'YYYYMMDD') > TRUNC(sysdate)
)
select c.*
from cte c 
where exists (
  select 1 from cte
  where partner2 = c.partner2 and partner1 <> c.partner1
)
```